# Where can I catch the different types of fish?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I'm currently trying to obtain the best equipment possible in preparation for the final boss and the survival dungeon. However, in order to do so, I need to take on a challenge of a...decidedly different nature from anything else in the game. I need to spend my time fishing.

Unfortunately, it seems that I don't exactly have the patience for it; there are so many different fish and so many different possible locations to fish for them that I end up feeling exhausted when I look at the amount of fish required to earn each reward. I don't want to go fishing for hours trying to find one particular type of fish only to discover that it's not even in the water pools that I've been trying.

So, to help me get done with this as quickly as possible: where can I catch each type of fish? In what sort of water or lava are they found? Are there any fish that can only be caught in one particular stage/location?

Answer (score 1):

There are many fish and many places, so it is best that you follow this table
[image: Chantelise Fish Table]

Answer (score 0):

There's 46 different types of fish, some rarer than others, and trying to summarize all of them along with every location would be a very long answer, but if you just want to know the minimum amount of places to find most fish, then [Steam's incomplete guide to fishing](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=231786423) would be a good choice, with the comments filling in for some info, while the [GameFAQs guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/980250-chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters/faqs/62815) given by Doug Dawson is more comprehensive.

This currently incomplete list of the possibly the fewest / easiest locations needed to fish in to get all of the fish, drawn from the Steam Guide and the GameFAQs guide, is:

> Town Fountain: Penguin, Little Blackfish, Clione

> Ignan Ruins Mural Room
> South-western hole: Little Redfish, Firefish, Taiyaki, Boiled Octopus

> Sealed Palace: The Lonely Ship
> Eastern side: Octopus, Blue Shark, Salmon, Manta, Yellowfin Tuna
> Western side: Lobster, Star Snapper, Anglerfish, Hammerhead, Aramaki Salmon
> Front of the tip: Coelacanth

> Zephyran Ruins:
> Emperor-Bug's Tomb: Sea Cucumber, Little Blackfish, East-sea Mackerel,
> Pufferfish
> Emperor-Bug's Tomb (Dark pool without yellow bug juice): Sea Cucumber,
> Piranha, Giant Oarfish, Aramaki Salmon

> Zephyran Ruins: Floating Gardens
> Little Blackfish, Mantis Shrimp, Rainbow Trout, Mecha-Coelacanth, Sperm Whale (Cast line right into centre of pool, biggest
> fish available), Axolotl

Answer (score -1):

I found a very long list of fish types and locations here:

[GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/980250-chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters/faqs/62815)

The list is very long, so I'm not sure I should post all the content here. But, here's the Table of Contents on the list:

> Table of Contents
>
> 1. Introduction
> 2. List of fish
> 3. Exchange requirements
> 4. Locations
> 5. Acknowledgements and credits
> 6. Contact information
> 7. Version history
> 8. Legal notice